# Get the ref of a functional component dynamically - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to access my ref with a string variable that passed from props and contains the ref name that I want to get. something like this:

```
function MyComponent(props) {

    const myFirstRef = useRef();
    const mySecondRef = useRef();
    const myThirdRef = useRef();

    function handleClick() {
        const targetRef = props.targetRef;

        // The `targetRef` is a string that contains
        // the name of the one of the above refs!
        // I need to get my ref by string
        // ...
    }

    return (
        <div ref={myFirstRef}>
            <div ref={mySecondRef}>
                <div ref={myThirdRef}>
                    <button onClick={handleClick}>Find Ref and Do Something</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

The `targetRef` is a string that contains the name of the above refs!

In class components there is `this.refs` and I could do what I want easily.

Comment: You can save your refs into a single object with different keys as it's name. Then you can access your ref with the object notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a dictionary as object for mapping given *key* `targetRef` **to** a specific *reference*:

```
const ref = useRef({ first: undefined, second: undefined, third: undefined });
ref.current[targetRef];
```

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const RefContainer = ({ targetRef }) => {
  const ref = useRef({ first: undefined, second: undefined, third: undefined });

  const handleClick = () => {
    const coolRef = ref.current[targetRef];
    console.log(coolRef);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={node => (ref.current.first = node)}>
      <div ref={node => (ref.current.second = node)}>
        <div ref={node => (ref.current.third = node)}>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Find Ref and Do Something</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return <RefContainer targetRef="third" />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit react-antd-styled-template]